# SFTP, SCP, and FTP client for OS X

Tags: linux, macos, winscp

I am looking for a free SFTP, SCP, and FTP client for OS X 10.7. Using this, I would like to have a GUI client that connects to a linux box to view and copy files (I used WinScp to connect to linux box from my Windows machine). Can you please suggest me something that works for my scenario. Currently, I am using ssh and scp.

Thanks,

Venkat

Answer (score 8):

[Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch) is an open source FTP, SFTP client for mac. Works great!

Comment: $23.99 in Mac App Store.

Comment: That's only on the App Store. If that price bothers you, you can get the free version as well straight from the website, plus you can compile it yourself (https://github.com/iterate-ch/cyberduck).

Comment: No SCP support in Cyberduck

Answer (score 4):

http://filezilla-project.org/

I believe this covers all your bases.
Free
gui
ftp
ssh
sftp

Comment: how to set about JumpMachine. If I want to connect B, but I must connect to A, then on A to connect to B